# How do I reduce the padding around text in Android xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 1 inch high text but the box of the view takes up 1.5 inches so there is 1/4 inch of black space above and below the white lettering.  I want to reduce that 1/4 inch so that I can get 5 lines of text on my 6 inch screen instead of just 4.  I can move them closer together with  android:lineSpacingMultiplier=".66" but this just moves the boxes closer together and the 1/4 inch of black space covers the text of the nearby line.  android:includeFontPadding="false" does nothing.  Negative padding does nothing.  Putting in android:lineSpacingExtra="-50sp" also just has the black margin cover the adjacent line of text.  I want to get rid of the margin (actually, just most of it).

I have tried every option I can think of including the obvious ones of padding and margins and padding discussed above including zero and negative numbers.  I can't find a simple diagram showing what controls the space in a view above the actual text.

How do I reduce this wasted space?

(my internet was down for the last 2 hours so it took me some time to respond.  Sorry)

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="10.01"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimeToLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="10.02"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimeToKill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textTimeToLine"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="10.03"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimeToPin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textTimeToKill"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="10.03"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimeToCB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textTimeToPin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="10.03"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Menu" 
    android:onClick="onMenu"
    android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this screen shot, you can see that the border or margin around the fond is the area I want to reduce.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Changing the font size is an option. Generally you want some kind of space between the line above. to improve readability

Comment: Padding controls how far in the text is from the edge of the View.  You've tried setting this to 0 and it didn't work?

Comment: @Atlos I set the padding to 0 and still have 1/4 inch of padding above the lettering.  In addition I have android:includeFontPadding="false".

Comment: @Doomsknight I want 1 inch high letters and think 1/4 inch between them should be enough.  That would allow 5 lines.  That almost works if I put in negative line spacings if I overlap the black areas but there is still a little bit of clipping of the lettering.  There really should be a way to reduce this black border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some negative top and bottom margin.  Things get messy though if you have fancy backgrounds.

Comment: I don't know how many times I thought I tried that but it worked.  Thank you.  android:layout_marginBottom="-25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25sp"

Answer (score 0):

Use negative values in the padding element.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to padding/margin set in **textTimeToPin** view. If you have set any spacing to this view so it will affect the placement of **textTimeToCB** since it is set to be displayed below it.

Review your xml for surrounding views or paste it entirely for us to have a better observation.

Comment: All the views have android:includeFontPadding="false" and are the same as the view I posted.  This is just a test case with 5 identical views except for the name.  I will post the entire xml.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```