# TextView digit taking too much space

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I know that this has already been asked a tons of times but I have a different question.

When I set a single digit in a textview and I set the `textSize` to be a certain big value (in my case `15pt`) this is what pretty much happen:

[image: TextView unused space]

As you can see, the editor show a lot of unused space on top and bottom of the number. I know that this is somewhat font-related.

Is there any way to fix this?

Just for clarification, I'm adding a code so you can test yourself:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

Further clarification, the red rectangles show the space I'd like to remove:

[image: TextView unused space - clarification]

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dial_number_two"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_number"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:textSize="4pt"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting the background of your `TextView` to a color and tell me what happens: `android:background:#ff0000`

Comment: This happens: http://i.imgur.com/RvytfbK.png

Comment: This seems really wrong, when using this method you are supposed to see a red box that is touched the edges of the number, are you manipulating the `TextView` by any way using code ? maybe you apply some padding or something else ?

Comment: Really nothing, no custom textview, no padding, nothing. This is why I came up to this question.

Comment: What happens to the views surrounding the `TextView` ? I can see a square containing a circle containing the `TextView` maybe you can post some more xml code ?

Comment: Just edited. However, this happens with an empy layout as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78925/discussion-between-tomtsagk-and-matteo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

which excludes top and bottom padding for font accents.

Comment: Though your answer do not work for me, I think I've found a workaround to my problem, at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886509/how-do-i-reduce-the-padding-around-text-in-android-xml-layout.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue and almost solved it by setting the textview's height equal to it's textsize.

So, in your case, set the `TextView` height to 15pt, or 15sp if you use sps for text size.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! However, this is going to cut the font. I don't know if I'm clear enough