# Android Remove default margins in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How to remove default spacing for elements in RelativeLayout?

[image: example]

I have tried setting negative margins, and weight property, but not getting any results.

I am trying to remove that space so that I do not have that vertical length of my ListView row.

This guy was doing something similar, which is second problem I have, but that approach with negative margins is not working.
[How do I reduce the padding around text in Android xml layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886509/how-do-i-reduce-the-padding-around-text-in-android-xml-layout/11886912)

How to you remove that space?

Shorter version of the cell XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/OrderRows"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    style="?commonRowStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderStatus"
            style="?orderParameterStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/orderStatusSuspendedMobile"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSecondary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filled"
            style="?orderParameterStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="filled"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this style

```
    style="?commonRowStyle"
```

Comment: Seriously, I have never looked into that... There is 5px margin set there... Eh.. Tnx